How to debug "[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings" in NextJS?
I have a NextJS app that keeps spewing out these warnings every now and then:
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (118kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (115kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (116kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (118kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (117kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (119kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (115kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (116kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (118kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (117kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (118kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (115kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (116kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (118kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (117kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (119kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (115kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (116kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
...

What do I do with these? How do I find the source of the problem? Or should I just ignore these?

Do you have any updates ? I also have it and I wonder if it is not slowing down my app

Are you using any UI library? if yes, which one?

Im using Mantine for various components

Issue might be due to tree shaking not being enabled when using Mantine in Next.js app router
Add the following in the next.config.mjs
experimental: {
    optimizePackageImports: ['@mantine/core', '@mantine/hooks'],
  }, 

From the mantine docs: https://mantine.dev/guides/next/#app-router-tree-shaking
here is a discussion about this issue: https://github.com/vanilla-extract-css/vanilla-extract/issues/374

@RubekJoshi Op is also using mantine as a component library

Sometimes this error can be caused be encoding and decoding large strings (so make sure you aren't doing that). But more often than not this an issue with Next.js.
Update Next.js
I used to get this error in my Next app when running version 13 after upgrading to 14 the issue was fixed.
You can upgrade Next.js by running:
npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest @types/react
See the official upgrade guide for all breaking changes.
Use Turbo pack
Turbopack is almost stable and is more performant than Webpack. Simply add the    --turbo flag to the next start command:
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --turbo",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }
}

Note there are some breaking changes by switching to Turbpack. The main one is a lack of a webpack() function in next.config.mjs. See the full list here.
Check for file system corruption
I have already written an answer on Stack Overflow detailing how to solve corruption issue with Next.js.
TLDR: Try deleting cached files, turning off file syncing, or upgrading your Next.js and Node installation.

Use Buffers for Serialization: Update your next.config.js with that process,

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
